# Table rows are getting increased every time

Tags: jquery, html

I am displaying a table on a model pop-up on clicking of a div. Table data is dynamic, i.e., it's coming from an api response. But the problem is that when i am closing the pop-up and again clicking on the div to open the model pop-up, then table rows are getting appended to the rows which have generated earlier. I am not able to understand this behavior. Ideally, when we are opening the model pop-up then table also should be generated freshly.

Note that I have hard-coded the response in the JS just for reference.

```html
<table id="quality_table" style="margin-top: 25px">
  <thead id="qualityTableHead">
    <tr id="qualityTableTR">
      <th></th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="qualityTableBody">
    <tr id="qualityTableData"></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
var data = [{
  "projectStatus": "ERROR",
  "buildName": "otfa_R5-10_3",
  "ignoredConditions": false,
  "build": "Build 1",
  "conditions": [{
    "comparator": "GT",
    "metricKey": "new_security_rating",
    "errorThreshold": 1,
    "actualValue": 0,
    "periodIndex": 1,
    "status": "ERROR"
  }, {
    "comparator": "GT",
    "metricKey": "new_reliability_rating",
    "errorThreshold": 1,
    "actualValue": 0,
    "periodIndex": 1,
    "status": "ERROR"
  }, {
    "comparator": "GT",
    "metricKey": "new_maintainability_rating",
    "errorThreshold": 1,
    "actualValue": 0,
    "periodIndex": 1,
    "status": "OK"
  }, {
    "comparator": "LT",
    "metricKey": "new_coverage",
    "errorThreshold": 80,
    "actualValue": 0,
    "periodIndex": 1,
    "status": "ERROR"
  }, {
    "comparator": "GT",
    "metricKey": "new_duplicated_lines_density",
    "errorThreshold": 3,
    "actualValue": 0,
    "periodIndex": 1,
    "status": "ERROR"
  }]
}, {
  "projectStatus": "SUCCESS",
  "buildName": "otfa_R5-91_2",
  "ignoredConditions": false,
  "build": "Build 2",
  "conditions": [{
    "comparator": "GT",
    "metricKey": "new_security_rating",
    "errorThreshold": 1,
    "actualValue": 0,
    "periodIndex": 1,
    "status": "ERROR"
  }, {
    "comparator": "GT",
    "metricKey": "new_reliability_rating",
    "errorThreshold": 1,
    "actualValue": 0,
    "periodIndex": 1,
    "status": "ERROR"
  }, {
    "comparator": "GT",
    "metricKey": "new_maintainability_rating",
    "errorThreshold": 1,
    "actualValue": 0,
    "periodIndex": 1,
    "status": "OK"
  }, {
    "comparator": "LT",
    "metricKey": "new_coverage",
    "errorThreshold": 80,
    "actualValue": 0,
    "periodIndex": 1,
    "status": "ERROR"
  }, {
    "comparator": "GT",
    "metricKey": "new_duplicated_lines_density",
    "errorThreshold": 3,
    "actualValue": 0,
    "periodIndex": 1,
    "status": "ERROR"
  }]
}, {
  "projectStatus": "WARNING",
  "buildName": "otfa_R5-9_1",
  "ignoredConditions": false,
  "build": "Build 3",
  "conditions": [{
    "comparator": "GT",
    "metricKey": "new_security_rating",
    "errorThreshold": 1,
    "actualValue": 0,
    "periodIndex": 1,
    "status": "ERROR"
  }, {
    "comparator": "GT",
    "metricKey": "new_reliability_rating",
    "errorThreshold": 1,
    "actualValue": 0,
    "periodIndex": 1,
    "status": "ERROR"
  }, {
    "comparator": "GT",
    "metricKey": "new_maintainability_rating",
    "errorThreshold": 1,
    "actualValue": 0,
    "periodIndex": 1,
    "status": "OK"
  }, {
    "comparator": "LT",
    "metricKey": "new_coverage",
    "errorThreshold": 80,
    "actualValue": 0,
    "periodIndex": 1,
    "status": "ERROR"
  }, {
    "comparator": "GT",
    "metricKey": "new_duplicated_lines_density",
    "errorThreshold": 3,
    "actualValue": 0,
    "periodIndex": 1,
    "status": "ERROR"
  }]
}];

$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  $('#quality_table').find('tbody').append('<tr id=qualityTableData><td>' + value.build + '</td>' + '<td>' + value.projectStatus + '</td></tr>');
});
```

Please help me to resolve this strange issue. May be i am missing a little part. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: you will have to clean the table html before appending again. i will post the code soon

Comment: It's because `append()` adds to existing content. To clear this out, call `$('#quality_table').find('tbody').empty()` before your `$.each()` loop

Comment: Thanks Both of You. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to clean the table before append data

```js
$('#quality_table').find('tbody').empty();

$.each(data, function(key,value) {
                $('#quality_table').find('tbody').append('<tr id=qualityTableData><td>'+value.build+'</td>'+'<td>'+value.projectStatus+'</td></tr>');
            });
```

Comment: Thanks Sachin..I was missing this little part, thanks for your help.